# Google Cloud Messaging Chat Application--unable to resolve super class

Tags: android, superclass, lcom

I am newer to Android but have located an excellent source for creating a multi-user chat app.  The tutorial is here: http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/1/

Or fork a users repository here: 
https://github.com/erikswed/InstaChatX

The issue arises whereby after downloading the github app and and resolving dependencies, the application compiles and opens briefly on my Android device, so that I can see the spash page and main icon, but soon crashes and get the error as:

[image]

I apologize for sounding so ignorant, but what is this error implying? Any insight in how to resolve?

Comment: Hi, don't know if you care anymore but you should look at the log until you find the blue hyperlink which shows the exact line in the code that your application is failing on. Once you have id the line, you can come back here, post the line, and someone here should be able to help you.